# No Package Hierarchy Importing Project in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, import, package

I've been trying to import a project that works on a friend's computer, however no matter what I try, the package hierarchy is completely lost and the result is this[image: packages without hierarchy]

Has anyone seen this issue before? I've been struggling with it for a while. Occasionally creating a new project and copying in the src folder works, but I've been unsuccesfful in my recent attempts.

Comment: Please show the .project and .classpath files. If maven is involved, please show the pom.xml.

Comment: Just realized that our gitignore has \*.classpath. *Facepalm*. Pretty sure adding those back in will fix it.

Comment: I actually saw this in the past few days while importing some apache commons libraries. If memory serves, when I got those weird grey packages, I had copied and pasted too high up the directory tree... like math3, instead of org.apache.commons.math3 (really /org/apache/commons/math3). But I spent a lot of time horsing around with Eclipse library issues, including the library won't update unless you restart Eclipse thing, so memory may not serve.

Comment: Did you try importing as a Maven project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out we weren't including the .classpath file in the source control. *Facepalm*.  Good answers, though.

Comment: That's generally a good thing. That file is Eclipse-specific and future coworkers who are Netbeans and IntelliJ users may not appreciate it. ;)

Answer (score 1):

The presentation of packages is a user option.  Click the little down-arrow at the top of the package panel, then select "Package Presentation" from flat to hierarchical.

Answer (score 0):

It could also be that the folders are not listed in the project as Source Folders. Go to the project properties and check that the root folders (looks like "data" and "src" here) are listed as source folders in the Build Path.